# How to get a multidimensional array of my menu?

Tags: menus

I want to be able to get an array of all my pages in my chosen menu along with all it's sub menu items.

Using `wp_get_nav_menu_items` returns a single dimensional array with only the top level menu items.

Using `wp_nav_menu` returns HTML which isn't so helpful as I am using bootstrap so want to create the HTML structure myself.

Comment: you can use this filters to edit the menu elements : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_items/. if you don't want to change the datas but only the render of the menu, you need to create a new walker : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker

Comment: I don't really understand. What would I need the filters for? It already returns all the top level menu items from my selected menu. A filter isn't going to add submenu items to the response of the function is it?

I just want an array of my menu and submenu... Surely there is a simple way to achieve this and other people have come across this before?

Comment: If you're trying to use Bootstrap for your menu, this is a solved problem, use the Bootstap Nav Walker: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to get a multidimensional array of my menu?**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935423/how-do-i-generate-a-custom-menu-sub-menu-system-using-wp-get-nav-menu-items-in-w

Comment: Please include at least summary of the information, if you are linking elsewhere. Links die over time.

Answer (score 0):

Hierarchical array isn't something WP can provide out of the box, since that's not *how* it processes menus.

Generation of menu markup is done by a *Walker* class, which takes care of turning flat input into a resulting markup, with levels and everything.

So for custom menu markup it is a typical "WordPress way" to use a *custom walker* rather than write a completely custom routine with custom structure inputs.

Given Bootstrap popularity specifically, I am pretty sure you won't have much trouble finding ready-made Walker examples out there for it.